Error : hostname:3001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P3zvxuf:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
Server Code Node JS
My project is everything ok on the local host; I can send SMS, fetch data, etc. Then I deployed on my hosting server. After that, get data from mongoDB properly. Node Js all request handel properl.
However, the socket server connection failed. I attatched error screenshot . enter image description here
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config()
const path = require("path")
const app = express();
const port = 5000;
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())
const http = require('http')
const Server = require('socket.io').Server


const Message = require('./model/message.mode')

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server,{
    cors : {
      origin:"*"
    }
})



io.on("connection", (socket) =>{
  console.log("connection on")
  
  const loadMessages = async () =>{
    try{
      const messages = await Message.find().sort({Timestamp:1}).exec();
      socket.emit("chat", messages)
    }
    catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
  loadMessages()

  socket.on('newMessage', async(msg) =>{
    try{
      const newMessageCrt = new Message(msg)
      await newMessageCrt.save()
      io.emit('message', msg)
    }
    catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
  })

  socket.on("disconnect", () =>{
    console.log("disconnected")
  })
})

server.listen("5001", ()=>{
  console.log("socket server is running at 5001")
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello Again")
})
  
mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.user}:${process.env.pass}@arefins.mi8bj9m.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=arefins`)
.then(()=> {
    console.log('connent successfully in mongoDB');
    app.listen(port, () =>{
        console.log(`server run prot in : ${port}`)
    })
    
})
.catch((error)=>{console.log(error)})

Frontend Code From React Component
const WriteSMS = () => {
    const socketio = SocketClient("https://localhost:5001/")
    const [chats, setChats] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(!chats?.length){
            return;
        }
        else{
            const filtered = chats.filter(item => item.chatId == chatId)
            setFiteredSms(filtered)
        }
    }, [chats, chatId])
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        socketio.on("chat", (chats)=>{
            setChats(chats)
        })
    
        socketio.on('message', (msg) =>{
            setChats(previousChats => [...previousChats, msg])
        })
    
        return () =>{
            socketio.off('chat')
            socketio.off('message')
        }
    }, [])
    
    const sendSocket = (chat) =>{
        socketio.emit('chat', chat)
    }
        
    const handelSendSms = e =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        const smsTextInp = e.target.sms_text.value;
        const sendAt = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('bd-BD');
    
        const obj= {smsText: smsTextInp, profileId:loggedUserInfo._id, sendAt, chatId, smsType:"text"}
    
        sendSocket([...chats, obj])
        socketio.emit('newMessage', obj)
        document.getElementById("sms-send-form").reset()
    }
    
}


check the socket server port is properly allowed in server
